# Multidimensional boolean indexing of Pandas DataFrame - remove NaN rows and columns

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I have a Pandas DataFrame like

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1,-2,-3],[4,5,6],[1,3,4]])
```

which looks like

```
   0  1  2
0  1 -2 -3
1  4  5  6
2  1  3  4
```

I would like to get a subset of this DataFrame with only negative values

```
    1    2
0  -2   -3
```

I would like to try boolean indexing (but I don't see how to use 2 dimensional boolean indexing)

```
In [7]: df_flag = df < 0
In [8]: df_flag
Out[8]:
       0      1      2
0  False   True   True
1  False  False  False
2  False  False  False
```

So I did

```
In [15]: df[df_flag]
Out[15]:
    0   1   2
0 NaN  -2  -3
1 NaN NaN NaN
2 NaN NaN NaN
```

Isn't there a way to (automatically) remove columns and rows full of NaN when using 2 dimensional boolean indexing ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make 2 calls to [`dropna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html#pandas.DataFrame.dropna), `dropna` accepts a `thresh` param which won't drop the entire axis if there are `n` non-Na values so the following drops rows then columns:

```
In [283]:

df[df<0].dropna(axis=0, thresh=1).dropna(axis=1)
Out[283]:
   1  2
0 -2 -3
```

The result of the first `dropna`:

```
In [284]:

df[df<0].dropna(axis=0, thresh=1)
Out[284]:
    0  1  2
0 NaN -2 -3
```

**UPDATE**

the `axis` param accepts multiple args so in fact you can do it a single call, thanks @scls:

```
In [285]:

df[df<0].dropna(axis=[0,1], thresh=1)
Out[285]:
   1  2
0 -2 -3
```

Comment: Thanks I wasn't aware of `thresh` parameter. `df[df>1].dropna(axis=[0,1], thresh=1)` also works fine